# Unable to generate Signed Bundle - Android resource linking failed, error: invalid config 'auto' for -c option

Tags: android, android-studio

After the update of Android Studio to v 3.2 I have an error when made a first try to generate Signed Bundle:

```
    Android resource linking failed
    Output:  error: invalid config 'auto' for -c option.

    Command: /home/yuliia/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-linux.jar/3c2f2255ccccab2125c4cc0eaccd5fdd/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-linux/aapt2 link --proto-format\
            -I\
            /home/yuliia/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
            --manifest\
            /home/yuliia/Documents/projects/android_projects/OCRme/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/processReleaseManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
            -o\
            /home/yuliia/Documents/projects/android_projects/OCRme/app/build/intermediates/linked_res_for_bundle/release/bundleReleaseResources/bundled-res.ap_\
            -R\
            /home/yuliia/Documents/projects/android_projects/OCRme/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/color_abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml.flat\
            -R\
            /home/yuliia/Documents/projects/android_projects/OCRme/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/drawable-xhdpi-v4_abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png.flat\
            -R\
            /home/yuliia/Documents/projects/android_projects/OCRme/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/drawable-xxhdpi-v4_abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015.png.flat\
            -R\
    ....
     /home/yuliia/Documents/projects/android_projects/OCRme/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/layout_activity_get_more_requests.xml.flat\
            --auto-add-overlay\
        -0\
        apk\
        -c\
        auto\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-linux Daemon #0
```

How can I make it works?

Comment: Did you specify res auto or any other density config?

Comment: Sorry I meant "resConfigs" not res auto.

Comment: @Yuliia did you find a solution?

Comment: @saurabhdhillon Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be using the 'auto' option for resConfig. 'auto' has been deprecated from the standard build, and is not supported in the bundle (the warning probably got lost in the logs after the error popped up):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "auto"
    }
}
```

Non-'auto' resConfigs are still supported in the bundle, so just specify which languages you would like to keep, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "en", "fr"
    }
}
```